# Chrome issues with scrollTo

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, scrollto

Hi have navigation menu with two navigation arrows Prev and Next. This works fine in every browser (Firefox, IE, Opera, Safari) except in Chrome. It doesn't even get a error message when the button is pressed.

Could someone please take a look on the code for the buttons. Am i missing something?

Thank you!

```
function scroll(direction) {        
    var scroll, i, positions = [], here = $(window).scrollTop(), collection = $('.box'), duration = 750, easing = "easeOutExpo";

    collection.each(function() {
        positions.push(parseInt($(this).offset()['top'], 10));
    });

    for( i = 0; i < positions.length; i++ ) {
        if( direction == 'next' && positions[i] > here ) { 
            scroll = collection.get(i);
            break;
        }
        if( direction == 'prev' && i > 0 && positions[i] >= here ) { 
            scroll = collection.get(i-1); 
            break;
        }
    }

    if(scroll) {
        $.scrollTo( scroll, { duration: duration, easing: easing });
    }

    return false;
}

$("a#prev, a#next").click(function() {
    return scroll($(this).prop( 'id' ));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved when i downgraded the jQuery version from 1.8.2 to 1.6.2